# What does FROM command do in Dockerfile?

Tags: python, docker

I just started with Docker and also have no exprience with Linux so far. My goal is to set up container that runs a python script.

I found this very nice documentation: [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/docker-for-python-development-83ae714468ac). Everything is clear to me. Except how the `FROM` command works in detail. In the documentation this command is used:

```
FROM python:3.6.7-alpine3.6
```

How does Docker know where the specific version of python is located on the Linux system?

For example: I'm used to work with conda and having there different environments. Let's say I have an environment called "py36" how would be the right `FROM` command that Docker finds the right path to my enviroment?

Comment: A docker container is isolated with all it's dependencies inside the container, when you pull an image for python:3.6 then it has the 3.6 interpreter installed within the container, you then need to put your code inside that container to run it. If you put python 2.7 code in a 3.6 container, you're going to have problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `FROM` command that you see in the `Dockerfile` does not work as you think it will.

It is the base image upon which your image is going to be built.

Here in your case, The base image is `alpine3.6` distribution which has `python 3.6.7` installed.

It searches for the base image on something called `Docker hub` where all such images are present.

The base image is just like an OS which doesn't have anything to do with your machine OS.

Let's say you are using `Ubuntu OS` now and if you mention the `alpine-3.6` in your Dockerfile, it means you are running `alpine-3.6` OS container on top of your machine

More on `FROM` command can be found [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#from).

Comment: Ok, now I understand. That means, if I want to build a python enviroment from scratch I need to create an image, upload it to the Docker hub and "link" that with the `FROM` command. Is this correct?

Comment: Nope. You don't need to create an image from scratch. Many people have already built the base images that comes installed with `Python`. All you need to do is use it using the `FROM` keyword. More can be found at https://hub.docker.com/_/python?tab=description

Answer (score -1):

FROM defines the base image for your container. Basically this base image comes from official Docker Hub registry. You can see the list of images: https://hub.docker.com/search/?q=&type=image&image_filter=official
If Docker is not able to recognize the image in your local, docker will pull it from  Docker Hub. If you have some unique images in local or in your own docker registry then you can use them as base image for the further images.